# Problem with multi checkboxes value in metabox?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, theme-development, custom-field, metabox

I'm a beginner and I have a problem with a part of the script that I found in a post. Practically when printing the checkboxes it does it outside the table. I can't bring the content of the foreach into the variable $input.

is there anyone who can help me and tell me how to change the foreach part of the checkboxes?

Thanks a lot

here is the screenshot

[image]

```
<?php
class custommetamasterMetabox {
    private $screen = array(
        'masters',
    );
    private $meta_fields = array(

        array(
            'label' => 'Abstract',
            'id' => 'abstract',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Download Brochure',
            'id' => 'download-brochure',
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Script contact form',
            'id' => 'script_form',
            'type' => 'textarea',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Durata del master',
            'id' => 'duratadelmaster_49527',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Area',
            'id' => 'area_master',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'MBA',
                'Marketing',
                'Risorse umane',
                'Turismo',
                'Fashion & Luxury',
                'Sport',
                'Agribusiness',
                'Sanità',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'formula',
            'label' => 'Formula',
             'type' => 'select',
             'options' => array(
                    'Full Time',
                    'Part Time',
                    'Executive',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Inizio del master',
            'id' => 'iniziodelcorso_26128',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Lingua del master',
            'id' => 'linguadelmaster_75355',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        //array(
        //  'label' => 'Formula del master',
        //  'id' => 'partecipanti_31742',
        //  'type' => 'text',
        //),

        array(
        'label' => 'Modalità',
        'id'    => 'modalita',
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',
        'desc'  => '',
        'options' => array (
                'Roma' => array (
                'label' => 'Roma',
                'value' => 'Roma'
            ),

                'On-line' => array (
                'label' => 'On-line',
                'value' => 'On-line'
            )
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Posti liberi Roma',
            'id' => 'pl_roma',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Posti liberi On-line',
            'id' => 'pl_online',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Immatricolazioni (%)',
            'id' => 'immatricolazioni',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Testo aggiuntivo',
            'id' => 'testo_aggiuntivo',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Menu interno',
            'id' => 'menu_interno_',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Interviste correlate',
            'id' => 'interviste_correlate',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
    );
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_fields' ) );
    }
    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->screen as $single_screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'masters',
                __( 'Masters', 'textdomain' ),
                array( $this, 'meta_box_callback' ),
                $single_screen,
                'advanced',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }
    public function meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'custommetamasterMetabox_data', 'custommetamasterMetabox_nonce' );
        $this->field_generator( $post );
    }
    public function field_generator( $post ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            $label = '<label for="' . $meta_field['id'] . '">' . $meta_field['label'] . '</label>';
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_field['id'], true );
            switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {

                case 'textarea':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<textarea class="large-text" id="%s" name="%s" rows="5">%s</textarea>',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_value
                    );
                    break;
                case 'wysiwyg':
                    ob_start();
                    wp_editor($meta_value, $meta_field['id']);
                    $input = ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();
                    break;
                case 'select':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<select multiple id="%s" name="%s">',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id']
                    );
                    foreach ( $meta_field['options'] as $key => $value ) {
                        $field_value = !is_numeric( $key ) ? $key : $value;
                        $input .= sprintf(
                            '<option %s value="%s">%s</option>',
                            $meta_value === $field_value ? 'selected' : '',
                            $field_value,
                            $value
                        );
                    }

                    $input .= '</select>';

                    break;

                case 'checkbox_group':

                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<div id="%s" name="%s">',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id']
                    ); 
                    foreach ( $meta_field['options'] as $option ) {
                      echo '<div id="'.$option['value'].'"><input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$meta_field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"', $meta_value && in_array($option['value'], $meta_value) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' /><label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label></div>';
                    }
                    $input .= '</div>';
                    break;
                default:
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                        $meta_field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'class="regular-text"' : '',
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['id'],
                        $meta_field['type'],
                        $meta_value
                    );
            }
            $output .= $this->row_format( $label, $input );
        }
        echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
    }
    public function row_format( $label, $input ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<tr><th scope="row">%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
            $label,
            $input
        );
    }
    public function save_fields( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['custommetamasterMetabox_nonce'] ) )
            return $post_id;

        $nonce = $_POST['custommetamasterMetabox_nonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'custommetamasterMetabox_data' ) )
            return $post_id;

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;

        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ) ) {
                switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                }
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
            } else if ( $meta_field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], '0' );
            }
        }
    }
}
if (class_exists('custommetamasterMetabox')) {
    new custommetamasterMetabox;
};
```

Comment: You are echoing the checkbox instead of appending it in $input variable. Check statement inside foreach loop.

Comment: Inside `foreach` for `checkbox_group` you should append to `$input` variable  and you use `,` instead of `.` (twice) to concatenate strings. Before and after `$meta_value && in_array($option['value'], $meta_value)`.